# Creating models (levels) for a Unity game. Do I create 1 model or several?

Tags: modeling

I hope there is an actual answer to this question.

What I'm trying to accomplish over all is to keep the amount of RAM used to a minimum. I'm not too sure about how Unity handles this, and that's question for another forum anyway. I'm wondering is it generally better to create small .blend files and assemble them in the game engine of choice or have one large level and let the game engine handle the level loading.

At the same time I'm also wondering about UV mapping large levels. For example I'm working on a building. Its rather simple single level school. I've build the model no problem. I'm just wondering should I break it down into individual rooms, then reassemble them into the "building" in the game engine of choice? Or even build each room separately and assemble them into another .blend file, as the whole building?

I guess what I'm really asking is: How do large/successful game developers handle large level creation?

I'm sure the answer varies depending on the device your product is aiming for. Lets assume a tablet for now.

Comment: please only ask one question at a time, you can ask multiple questions, but in different posts.

Comment: Large, successful game developers have people who do *only* level creation. come to the [renderfarm](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) if you want to join a game project, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @Vince Scalia I guess it did phrase it as two questions. I didn't mean too. I was trying to ask is it better to make small chunks of a map or one large one.
Thank you for the offer, I'll keep it in mind. I'm just doing this in my free time as a hobby, and if I'm going to do it might as well do it right. Right?

Answer (score 2):

Creating smaller parts (i.e. separate rooms, halls, corners) is referred to as "Modular structuring".

Modularity is faster, easier to get great results from, and is easier to change up and reuse, but it comes at the cost of adaptability, so this really depends on your game. If you're doing a level where everything is uniform anyway, like a subway tunnel or the interior of a military base or vehicle, modularity can be your best friend. Other cases, like a ranch house or an art center (cause they usually involve weird architecture) can create serious problems for the modular output due to the fact that you would be creating so many different components you might as well just do the whole thing by hand. It's really a case by case study, but I generally use a mix, modular where it works, and conventional where it doesn't.

If you do chose to use some modular structuring, you should follow a few rules:

- Always use standardized sizes (this will help with assembly, avoiding trying to find the happy-medium between a 2.5 foot door and a 3 foot door.)
- make everything the same theme
- Place the origin of the modular sections at one edge or corner. (so you can use snapping to position them.)

someone has a great set of tutorials on modular structuring, but I can't find it right now, so I'll post a link when I do.